# How can I ping my vagrant box with ansible?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine, ansible

I'm following a [tutorial](http://www.thedreaming.org/2014/11/04/vagrant-ansible/) showing how to setup a vagrant vm to practice using ansible.

I have the following directory structure, files, and configuration:

```
➜  trusty64 tree
.
├── Vagrantfile
├── ansible
│   ├── hosts
│   ├── playbooks
│   └── roles
└── ansible.cfg

3 directories, 3 files
➜  trusty64 cat ansible/hosts
[vagrantboxes]
vagrant ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222

[vagrantboxes:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
➜  trusty64 cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
hostfile = ./ansible/hosts
roles_path = ./ansible/roles
➜  trusty64 vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/max/Desktop/vagrantboxes/trusty64/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

But when I try pinging my vm it doesn't work:

```
➜  trusty64 ansible all -m ping
vagrant | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
    "unreachable": true
}
➜  trusty64 ansible all -m ping -u vagrant
vagrant | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: First make sure that you can ping the guest VM from the host in the **command line**. If it doesn't work, then resolve this issue first and then move on to Ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also want to put your ansible management node into a vagrant vm itself. This [tutorial](https://sysadmincasts.com/episodes/43-19-minutes-with-ansible-part-1-4) shows it quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Vagrant changes insecure key on the first VM run.
Change `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` to the actual key from `vagrant ssh-config`:

```
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/Users/max/Desktop/vagrantboxes/trusty64/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```